# Swift nested if else, making it better

Tags: swift, if-statement, nested, tableview

Hi my code is very inefficient which frustrates me, I don't know how to make it better. I am a beginner, does anyone have any suggestions for improvement?

The issue is that the length of questioncount is 12 and I want to increase the progressbar every time I go from page 1 to page 2 etc. until the last page 12
Is there any other possibility?
Thanks for your time

```
var setProgress = questionCount
            print (setProgress)
            
            if setProgress == 1 {
                progressBar.setProgress(0.08, animated: true)
            } else if setProgress == 2{
                progressBar.setProgress(0.16, animated: true)
            } else if setProgress == 3{
                progressBar.setProgress(0.24, animated: true)
            } else if setProgress == 4{
                progressBar.setProgress(0.32, animated: true)
            } else if setProgress == 5{
                progressBar.setProgress(0.40, animated: true)
            } else if setProgress == 6{
                progressBar.setProgress(0.52, animated: true)
            } else if setProgress == 7{
                progressBar.setProgress(0.55, animated: true)
            } else if setProgress == 8{
                progressBar.setProgress(0.64, animated: true)
            } else if setProgress == 9{
                progressBar.setProgress(0.75, animated: true)
            } else if setProgress == 10 {
                progressBar.setProgress(0.88, animated: true)
            } else if setProgress == 11 {
                progressBar.setProgress(0.95, animated: true)
            } else {
                progressBar.setProgress(1, animated: true)
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have a small, contiguous range of valid integer `questionCount` values, you can create an array that indicates the progress bar's progress amount for each value of `questionCount`. The following code will handle all values of `questionCount`, make it easy to add or modify the progress amounts, and also gracefully handles unexpected values of setProgress:

```swift
let progressAmounts = [0, 0.08, 0.16, 0.24, 0.32, 0.40, 0.52, 0.55, 0.64, 0.75, 0.88, 0.95]

if progressAmounts.indices.contains(questionCount) {
    progressBar.setProgress(progressAmounts[questionCount], animated: true)
} else {
    progressBar.setProgress(1, animated: true)
}
```